# Modify list elements by passing it to a function

Tags: python

I am using pass-by-reference to change the case of strings in a list. This code seems not to be working:

```
def test(the_list):
    for word in the_list:
        word.lower()

the_list=["Python", "Programming"]
test(the_list)
print the_list
```

Expected output:

```
["python","programming"]
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python. You cannot change them in-place, even if you pass them "by reference".

Comment: "(In Python) arguments are passed using call by value (where the value is always an object reference, not the value of the object) [...] Actually, call by object reference would be a better description, since if a mutable object is passed, the caller will see any changes the callee makes to it (items inserted into a list)." https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
def test(the_list):
    for i in range(len(the_list)):
        the_list[i] = the_list[i].lower()

the_list=["Python", "Programming"]
test(the_list)
print the_list
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using a for loop, but it is much faster and more readable to use the bulit-in list comprehensions:

```
the_list=["Python", "Programming"]
the_list = [x.lower() for x in the_list]
print the_list
```

Comment: @ no_nome.  Did that.

Comment: watch out for this with large datasets though because instead of putting one list into memory you are putting two